# Convert percent into a decimal in html/ javascript

Tags: javascript

Javascript:

```
   var validate(s) = s.match ^( 100(?:\.0{1,2})? | 0*?\.\d{1,2} | \d{1,2}(?:\.\d     {1,2})? )% $ != null; 

   var str = value.match(/\/\/%//g);

    if(converted==NaN){
            alert('Input was not a number');
    }
    else if(converted != null) {

            var fracToDecimal = eval (value);

            alert(fracToDecimal);
    }
    else if(converted = str) {

            var percToDecimal = value/100;

            alert(percToDecimal);
    } }
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Hi user1464427, what have you tried so far?
The Stack Overflow Community  might be able to help you figure out the problem
but is not able to without concrete data and this is not a "write me some code" type of site.
Help us help you, by sharing the code you're using right now, possibly some sample data and any possible errors you encounter.
Adapt your question to include those and you'll surely get a helpful answer. Thanks for considering. :)

Answer (score 74):

So you have a string like: `50%`? How about:

```
var percent = "50%";
var result = parseFloat(percent) / 100.0;
```

Comment: `parseFloat` doesn't have a second argument

Comment: Very true. Force of habit from `parseInt` :)

Comment: Original question sucks, but this answer is perfect

Answer (score 21):

If you use `parseFloat`, it will read the string up until the first non-number character (the `%`)

```
var x = '20.1%';
var y = parseFloat(x); // 20.1
```

Then you can check if it's `NaN`, and convert it.

```
if(!isNaN(y)){
    y /= 100; // .201
}
```

Note: You need to use `isNaN` because `NaN === NaN` is `false` (JavaScript is weird).

---

**UPDATE**: I see you also have `fracToDecimal`  in there.  You don't need `eval` for that.  Just do a simple `split`.

```
var frac = '1/2';
var nums = frac.split('/');
var dec = nums[0]/nums[1];
```

Comment: Sorry to make it more clear I have fracToDeciaml in there because iI have to convert integers, fractionss, and percentages into decimals.

Comment: NaN !== NaN in any language. Just FYI.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the "%" is on the right hand of the string, just use `parseFloat(s)/100`

http://jsfiddle.net/TrCYX/1/

Answer (score -1):

I'm very late, but keeping it as itself if it is a decimal goes like this

```js
let val = "100%"
String(val).includes("%") ? parseFloat(val)/100 : parseFloat(val) //1
val = 1 //or val = "1"
String(val).includes("%") ? parseFloat(val)/100 : parseFloat(val) //1
```