# How to compare two percentage strings

Tags: javascript

I have two strings: `50%` and `60%`. I'm trying to compare the two strings and figure out that `60%` is bigger than `50%`. What would be the easiest and most clean way to compare the two strings? I can always remove the `%` sign, convert the strings to ints and compare them. But is there a better way?

Comment: Remove the percent sign and compare them, yes. The "better way" is to write a function that does this correctly, and write a test to verify it does it correctly.

Comment: `parseFloat(percent) / 100.0` ought to do it.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11088597/1563833)

Comment: `parseInt('50%') < parseInt('100%')`, for instance

Answer (score 4):

You can use parseInt to parse only the numeric part.

```
let x = "50%";
let y = "60%";
parseInt(x)>parseInt(y)?console.log(`${x} is greater than ${y}`):console.log(`${y} is greater than ${x}`);

Console: 60% is greater than 50%
```

Comment: If you had double percentages than parseFloat needs to be used

Comment: @lainatnavi Yes. But as per the original question, I believe this works good enough. But yes, in general this should be added.

Answer (score 0):

```
let percentage1 = parseFloat('50%');
let percentage2 = parseFloat('60%');

if (percentage1 <= percentage2) {
    // Code here
}
```

Comment: Provide some description about your answer

Answer (score 0):

Do a string replace to remove `%` and also parseInt it in comparison

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mvqw7x)

Answer (score 0):

```
function cmpPercentages(str1, str2){
    var per1 = parseFloat(str1);
    var per2 = parseFloat(str2);
    if(per1 > per2){
        return 1;
    }else if(per2 > per1){
        return -1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Where 1 means that the first percentage is higher, -1 that the first percentage is smaller than the second and 0 that they are equal, just like localeCompare's result.