# How to extract a number from a string with a percentage inside parentheses

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working with an API and there's a key value which is:

changesPercentage: "(-3.34%)"

how do I convert this string to number without percentage?

```
if (obj.profile.changesPercentage < 0) {
    document.getElementById('precentage').style.color = 'red';
}
```

I need to set the color to red if the number is negative and green if the number is positive, I tried parseInt() but its not working since there's also brackets.
not sure on how to be specific on the removal.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: A quick google gave me [a great answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11088597/13561410).

Comment: @OskarGrosser it's (maybe?) half the solution. Right now it's not going to work because of the brackets. So, if those are removed, then it can be used. However, with the latest update from OP, there might not even be a need to convert to a number at all, if it's only checking for negative or not negative.

Comment: You are right, I should have also linked to some technique of [replacing parts of a String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), if he actually wanted to convert the String to a decimal value.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good candidate for a regular expression.

```js
const myString = '(-123.45%)';
const regex = /[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)/;
const mynum = Number(myString.match(regex)[0]);
console.log(mynum); // -123.45
```